# Angular Google Map Integration

Tags: angular

I have created a Google Address component. Here are the files:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {GAdressService} from './gAddress.service';
import {Settings} from './../settings/settings';
import {SettingsService} from './../settings/settings.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'g-address',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: './gAddress.component.html',
    providers: [Settings,SettingsService],
    styleUrls: ['./gAddress.style.css'], 
})
export class GAddressComponent implements OnInit{
    private lat: number= -33.8688;
    private lng: number= 151.2195;

    constructor(private settings: Settings,private settingsService: SettingsService)
    {

    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.load_settings();
        this.initMap();
    }


    private load_settings()
    {
         this.settingsService.load().subscribe(
             (settings: Settings)=> this.settings= settings
         );
    }

    private initMap()
    {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng},
          zoom: 13
        });
        var card = document.getElementById('pac-card');
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
        var strictBounds = document.getElementById('strict-bounds-selector');

        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        // Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
        // so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
        // bounds option in the request.
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
        infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
        });

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          infowindow.close();
          marker.setVisible(false);
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.geometry) {
            // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
            // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
            window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
            return;
          }

          // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
          }
          marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
          marker.setVisible(true);

          var address = '';
          if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
              (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
          }

          infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
          infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
          infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
        // Autocomplete.
        function setupClickListener(id, types) {
          var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
          radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            autocomplete.setTypes(types);
          });
        }

        setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
        setupClickListener('changetype-address', ['address']);
        setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
        setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);

        document.getElementById('use-strict-bounds')
            .addEventListener('click', function() {
              console.log('Checkbox clicked! New state=' + this.checked);
              autocomplete.setOptions({strictBounds: this.checked});
            });
    }
}
```

My Component HTML file is:

```
<div style="display: block; width: 500px; height: 500px;">
    <div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
    <div>
    <div id="title">
        Autocomplete search
    </div>
    <div id="type-selector" class="pac-controls">
        <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
        <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

        <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
        <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>

        <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-address">
        <label for="changetype-address">Addresses</label>

        <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
        <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
    </div>
    <div id="strict-bounds-selector" class="pac-controls">
        <input type="checkbox" id="use-strict-bounds" value="">
        <label for="use-strict-bounds">Strict Bounds</label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pac-container">
    <input id="pac-input" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
    <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
    <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
    <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Above code works fine. But component's initMap function uses "document.getElementById" function to access some of the map elements. Due to this I am unable to use map component twice on single page. Any advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a reference to each element you need to access, for example, in the case of `id="map"`, you could do the following:

Template:

```
...

<div #map></div>

...
```

Component:

```
...

@ViewChild('map') private mapElem: ElementRef;

...
...
...

private initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElem.nativeElement, {
        center: {lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng},
        zoom: 13
    });
}

...
```